# Can I somehow execute my db/seeds.rb file from my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I am building a demo, and I want to make it very easy for a non-technical person to set up and run the demo.  I have built a seeds.rb file with lots of demo data in it.  I want to be able to reset the rails app to a known state by providing an administrator-level action via a page link.  I don't want to provide these non-tech demonstrators with a command line and rake, because they might shoot themselves in the foot.

I have looked into using load 'db/seeds.rb' within a method, but that doesn't quite do what I want.  I know I am missing something, but what?

Answer (score 98):

You can call `Rails.application.load_seed`. That's all `rake db:seed` does.

Comment: I just brought up my app with mongrel, opened a console, and typed 'Rails.application.load_seed'.  

I got the following:  NoMethodError: undefined method `load_seed' for #<Ixchanj::Application:0xb6a7f6a0>
 from /home/kenb/ruby/gems/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
 from /home/kenb/ruby/gems/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
 from (irb):18
 from :0
  
So, that didn't work.  What am I missing, besides 'load_seed'?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like `load_seed` won't be available until 3.1.0 (I found it from the master branch of Rails and didn't think to check it). In the meantime, you'll have to run it with: `load(Rails.root.join("db", "seeds.rb"))`

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the classic method:

```
bundle exec rails db:seed
```

But I guess, that you can also call `Rails.application.load_seed` as mentioned.