# How can I use seed data in factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing an app that let's users take a test online. The test has 2 sets of 18 questions which are randomized on the view. I'm trying to write tests to make sure that I get the correct 18 questions on each part. I'd like to create a factory that will hit the db and load in a random sequence of questions. Any idea how to do this? I can hard code the text but I actually want to test the seed data and DRY out my code by not repeating the questions in my seeds.rb and factory.rb.

Here's what I've done that is hard coded

```
Factory.define :test do |test|
    test.association :user
end

Factory.define :question do |question|
    question.phrase "2+2"
    question.answer "4"
    question.association :test
end
```

Then, in my tests, I can write something like:

```
@test = Factory(:test, :user => @user)
@question = Factory(:question, :test => @test)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if at the top of your spec/factories.rb you add the following line:

```
load(Rails.root.join("db", "seeds.rb"))
```

If you are using, Rails 3.1, you can use the following line instead.

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

I got this answer from: [Can I somehow execute my db/seeds.rb file from my rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212351/can-i-somehow-execute-my-db-seeds-rb-file-from-my-rails-app)