# Rails - In-app "database seed" button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seeding

I'm building a Rails app for my company. My *seeds.rb* file contains code to sync my list of users with our Office 365 directory, which needs to happen every time something changes in the directory, and I'm trying to build an in-app "seed" button so that people with no Rails/Heroku knowledge can initiate that process.

As you can see in the code excerpts below, I've figured out that I can do this by calling `rails db:seed` as a shell command, but it feels like there should be a less roundabout way to do this than a Rails app calling a shell command to perform an operation on itself.

Is there a way to actually run the code in seeds.rb from within the app, or is calling `rails db:seed` the closest I've got?

*app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb*

```
...
<li><%= link_to "Sync users with O365", seed_path %></li>
...
```

*config/routes.rb*

```
...
get '/seed', to: 'application#seed'
...
```

*app/controllers/application_controller.rb*

```
...
  def seed
    `rails db:seed`
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
...
```

Comment: you could always move your Seed loader code into a nice Class, then just create an instance of that class or use a class method to do the job in both your Rake task and when you click on that button.

Comment: Maybe something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212351/can-i-somehow-execute-my-db-seeds-rb-file-from-my-rails-app/5212588.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `Rails.application.load_seed` where you want in your code

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that one :) Definitely the way to go.

Comment: Wow, not only did that work, it also drastically boosted the operation's speed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

There is also:

```
MyAwesomeApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
```